# How to generate call to a mobile using asterisk

Tags: voip, asterisk

I am a college student and a complete newbie to asterisk.
I'm currently working on a project 'email to voice call'.
Using python i'v extracted the email & converted it into speech and saved in a WAV file.
Now using asterisk i want to generate call to the mobile of the user through my system.

I have read the book 'Asterisk: The Future Of Telephony' as suggested by many. But i'm still not able to understand what all things i need to setup to generate a call to mobile.
What i understood is that i need to configure two files i.e. sip.conf where i need to give the details of VoIP provider and extensions.conf for dial-plan. Asterisk will tell the VoIP provider to generate a call.

Now can anyone please tell me what things i need to setup other than these? Also can you help me in the configuration of these two files??

Please help. Any information will be appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully understand your case.

You want to generate call on user's mobile (cellular telephony)?
Or 
You want to generate call on user's mobile voip application?

If you case is second then you only need to configure 2 files as you have mentioned. And you can easily get pre-configured files from internet (voip-info.org).

But if you fall in to case one then you need following apart from those 2 files.

1. Additional hardware [FXO card](http://www.patton.com/technotes/fxs_fxo.pdf).
2. Need to configure zaptel driver for that FXO card.
3. One telephone line.

Comment: thanks for the reply..  
yes.. i want to generate call to the cell phone of the user..  
But uptil now what i understood was that after configuring the sip.conf (where i need to give the details of voip provider) and extensions.conf (dialplan script) file, some voip provider will send a call to the cell phone when given instructions by asterisk.  
Can you please elaborate why i need this additional hardware?  
and what do you mean by a telephone line?

Comment: If you go with provider then there is no need to use additional H/w. Asterisk some time behave as B2B UA. Means it works as client for server & as server for client. You got some user credential from you provider. Just configure(create profile) in sip.conf [http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+sip.conf] & create dial plan for that in extension.conf

Comment: thanks divyang.. i have written a detailed query for this.. If you can help please do so.. Thanks in advance... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025422/unable-to-generate-call-to-cell-phone-using-asterisk